# Appends throwing error on group by query on laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

The question model is added with an append attribute called is_common as shown below,

**Question.php**

```php
protected $appends = ['is_common'];

....

public function getIsCommonAttribute() {
    return $this->category->common;
}
```

It's working as expected when fetching lists or individual questions. But throws an error when querying with `group by`. The query includes `->groupBy('institute_id')`, Institutes may or may not have questions. the error and query as given below,

```php
$question_query = Question::query();
....
(clone $question_query)->select('institute_id', DB::raw("count(institute_id) as questions"))
                    ->orderBy('institute_id', 'ASC')
                    ->groupBy('institute_id')
                    ->get()->toArray();
```

> Trying to get property 'is_common' of non-object

What is the best way to solve this issue?

**note**: I could solve this by

```php
return $this->category ? $this->category->common : false;
```

but is this the right way to solve this or any other Please suggest.

Comment: I think we need to see your query :)

Comment: @Techno Query added Please check now.

Comment: I think the problem is that you are asking for the category relationship, but are not selecting the id to get to the category. If you don't select this, `$this->category` is always empty.

Comment: I tried with category_id also @Techno, but No Luck. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Are the category_id's you find linking to existing categories?

Comment: Yes @Techno, all the category are connected